# Taskbar (or Start) search is not showing all folders in disk C

Tags: windows, windows-11

I have a folder in disk C but when I search it in Start menu it won't show up. File folders like repos or document will though. Any way of fixing it? I am using windows 11

Comment: right click folder -> properties.  [Advanced] button on the general tab.  Make sure you have "Allow files in this folder to have contents indexed...".  This is supposed to be the way to control this and it may or may not work.

Comment: Yeahh it is on and files still not showing up

Comment: Rebuild the Search Index, after setting the *Indexing Options* to include the location of the folders, and, if you wish, Zip, CAB and other compressed formats in *File types*.

Comment: Yep, thats fixed it! Thx!